# Migrating Wordpress Uploads To Amazon S3

Tags: image, wordpress, .htaccess, amazon-s3

I currently use a plugin on wordpress that creates a carbon copy of the uploads in a s3 bucket whenever a new picture is added. The problem is on the same site there are about 700 pictures uploaded before we started to use this plugin that aren't on s3 and we need to free up some space. The plugin doesn't copy these old pictures over.

Does any one know of a way to redirect all the image urls to the s3 bucket instead if we manually copy the files over? Could this be done with a htaccess in the uploads folder?

Thanks for your help I am very bad with redirects and things and need to improve.

Jozef

Comment: what plugin do you use? e.g. `W3 total cache` does this extremely well - also uploading old files that were uploaded before you installed the plugin.

Comment: I didn't realise that was a feature of W3 Total Cache. Where in the plugin do you find that option?

Answer (score 2):

Using:

RedirectPermanent /wp-content/uploads http://xxxx.s3.amazonaws.com/wp-content/uploads

In your main .htaccess file should do the trick, note this will redirect all uploads (including potentially non-image uploads).

Answer (score 2):

No need to install any plugin. I did it by mapping wp-content/uploads to S3 bucket using S3FS. Refer [Moving wordpress uploads to Amazon s3 using S3FS](http://wordpress-tips4all.blogspot.in/2014/07/wordpress-uploads-to-amazon-s3-using-s3fs.html)

If you want to save space on your server, don't use use_cache option while mounting S3FS. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

try to use s3cmd
install it configure it by providing it access and secrate key of aws
then sync your upload folder or image folder with s3 bucket

and your done